# making an ajax call to controller action in rails

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, ajax

I am trying to make an ajax call to my controller

```
class PatientRecordController < ApplicationController
  def export
     ....
  end
end
```

In my javascript file i have

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    freezeTopRow($('#dataTable'));
    $("#export").click(function(){
        $.ajax({url: "patient_record/export", type: "POST"});
    });
});
```

when i inspect element and debug and when i click the export tag on my page. i hit the function however it never gets to the controller

Also I have 2 controllers and 2 views.  In my other controller and view I do the same thing and it works

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Have you checked that you `routes.rb` have something like:

```
post 'patient_record/export'
```

Maybe Rails doesn't know the route so the ajax isn't working (if you can get to the action from your browser it means that you have only a `GET` set, you can check that changing the type of the request in the ajax call)

Answer (score 2):

You also need a route for the `export` action in your `config/routes.rb` file, something like

```ruby
resources :patient_records do
  member do
    post :export
  end
end
```

You can check to see if this already exists by running `rake routes | grep 'export'`.

Comment: ...and I was just about to post a similar comment on your answer. :)